# Xcode - How do I specify what can and can't be inputted into a text field?

Tags: xcode, time, numbers, textfield

Hey guys, I basically have a working hours calculator in the works and I was wondering how I can disable certain numbers from being put into a field. For example, for the minutes field, I would like to prevent 61-99 being inputted. What sort of code would I need to make that work?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Xcode - Xcode is an IDE - you probably mean Cocoa or CocoaTouch, depending on whether you are developing for Mac OS X or iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up `NSFormatter`, specifically [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) or [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumberFormatter). A formatter can be added directly to a text field in InterfaceBuilder; you simply drag it from the palette onto the text field. You could also use a datepicker (`NSDatePicker`). You will find all of these in the various palettes in IB.